# select multiple files and load the file names to "Checked List Box"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I need to: open the file dialog box when a button clicked, and then I'll select multiple files, then click ok, then the files will appear on Checkedlistbox1. And I want the dialog box to remember the folder path which I browsed last (so when I click that button again, it will take me to that location). But when I just run "openfiledialog" I can't select multiple files, and when I add further code, the program gives errors. Please shed some light here. :)

```
Dim fbd As New OpenFileDialog With { _
            .Title = "Select multiple files", _
            .FileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)}

    If fbd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        CheckedListBox1.Items.AddRange(Array.ConvertAll(IO.Directory.GetFiles(fbd.FileNames), Function(f) IO.Path.GetFileName(f)))
    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a List(of String) in my test, you can change it so as to meet your needs.

```
    Dim fbd As New OpenFileDialog With { _
        .Title = "Select multiple files", _
        .Multiselect = True, _
        .FileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)}

    If fbd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        CheckedListBox1.AddRange(fbd.FileNames.Select(Function(f) IO.Path.GetFileName(f)))
    End If
```

> **EDIT**

I edited my code so as to use an object. The following is an example. You can use it to create the needed object for CheckBoxList

```
    Public Property CheckedListBox1 As New List(Of TestClass)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fbd As New OpenFileDialog With { _
        .Title = "Select multiple files", _
        .Multiselect = True, _
        .FileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)}

    If fbd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        CheckedListBox1.AddRange(fbd.FileNames.Select(Function(f) New TestClass With {.Name = IO.Path.GetFileName(f)}))
    End If
End Sub

Public Class TestClass
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

> **EDIT 2**

```
        Dim fbd As New OpenFileDialog With { _
            .Title = "Select multiple files", _
            .Multiselect = True, _
            .FileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)}

        If fbd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            CheckedListBox1.Items.AddRange(fbd.FileNames.Select(Function(f) IO.Path.GetFileName(f)).ToArray)
        End If
```

Comment: it gives an error, and instead of `CheckedListBox1.AddRange` you should have used `CheckedListBox1.Items.AddRange` I guess, but after replacing that also gives errors. 

`Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'AddRange' can be called without a narrowing conversion:`

Comment: As I told you for my test I created a List(Of String), yes the CheckListBox that you have is an other Object, so you need to convert the string to items that yout CheckListBox uses.

Comment: I edited my answer so that you can convert it to the object you need.

Comment: as I'm a beginner I have no idea how to do what you say. Can you please, test with the CheckListBox and rectify the code ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `InitialDirectory` property and a temporarily global string variable to remember your last open directory.

```
Dim LastDir As String = ""

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim fbd As New OpenFileDialog
    If LastDir = "" Then Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)

    With fbd
        .Title = "Select multiple files" ' Title of your dialog box
        .InitialDirectory = LastDir ' Directory appear when you open your dialog.
        .Multiselect = True 'allow user to select multiple items (files)
    End With

    If fbd.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then ' check user click ok or cancel

        LastDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(fbd.FileName) 'Update your last Directory.

        ' do your stuf here i.e add selected files to listbox etc.
        For Each mFile As String In fbd.FileNames
            CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(mFile, True)
        Next

    End If
```

this will remember your last open directory while your program is running/alive.
If you want your dialog box always remember last opened directory store `LastDir` in your program settings or in computer registry.

Comment: Thanks :) it helped me.

Comment: @lwarai Its my pleasure :)